# Pentaho - Execute simultaneouslyl stored procedures on different hosts

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pentaho, etl

I have the same stored procedure on different hosts like this:

```
Host1 -> sqlserveristance--> master(db) ---> sp_name
Host2 -> sqlserveristance--> master(db) ---> sp_name
....
```

For each stored procedure the execution time is long, that's why I would like to execute at the same time and not sequentially. Hosts name is stored inside a file, for every one I set environment variables to use in database connection parameter.

That is exactly what looks like my job:

```
Job1 Trasformation1.1 --read file and copy rows to result
Job2 ( checked "execute for every input row")
Trasformation2.1 --get rows from result and set variables Hostname
Trasformation2.2 -- use ${HostName} to execute sql script
```

But it seems that each SQL script is being run sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute in parallel same transformation with different parameters, then you can use `Transformation executor` step.

In order to specify the number of parallel threads, you can right-click the step, then select `Change number of Copies to start` option. Remember to set the `data movement` option of previous step to `round-robin` (not to the <s>`copy data`</s>), so that your previous step would distribute the output rows among copies of the Transformation executor.

You can map output columns of the previous step to the sub-transformation parameters on the `Parameters` tab.

Suggested workflow:

```
<Main.ktr>:
    [Text file input] Read connection details
     || data movement: round-robin
     ||
     \/
    [Transformation executor] (x2 copies, pass HostName column as a parameter)
    <sub-transformation.ktr>:
        [Execute SQL script] (use ${HostName} to execute sql script)
```